# How to select a swatch from Libraries by name using script?

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

I am looking for a script can search swatch by name from Libraries and select it to apply to foreground via a dialog. I can't find any script for Libraries.

[image: Example]

Comment: You may be out of luck as libraries are relatively new. Have a [read of this](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/photoshop-script-possible-to-load-images-from-cc-library/m-p/12507942).